# A JavaScript plugin to parse youtube url in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am looking for a plugin that would have the same functionality as any facebook input box - when you paste in a youtube (or several other video hosting site) links it will extract that url and show the video container.

Answer (score 0):

Just googled "url preview javascript" lead me to this: http://embed.ly/embed

Comment: That is a service, not a standalone plugin, but thanks for the search terms - I sometimes struggle with finding correct ones :)